# How to get column name from column chooser

Tags: jqgrid

I want to get list of column names from Column Chooser when click on ok button.

Note that the plugin is column chooser jqgrid.

Comment: And what have you tried? Where is your code?

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commertial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? Free jqGrid supports `onRemapColumns` callback on jQuery event `"jqGridRemapColumns"`, which will be called *after* changing the order of columns. One can examine `colModel` inside of the callback will shows you the new order of the columns.